# Python: delete list in list if 1st element in list is duplicated and 2nd element is lowest in lists series

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists. Each list has the same number of elements. I'd like to delete an entire list if a new list supersedes the old one based on a numeric key in the nth element that all the lists have. This numeric key is an increment of 1 starting from 1. Highest key is desired.

```
all = [[123, 1],[456, 1],[789, 1],[123,2],[456, 2],[789,1]]
```

The last element in each list is the key: 2 supersedes 1 etc... the output desired is:

```
[[123,2],[456,2],[789,1]]
```

Comment: Please try to write your own code, and post the errors you get instead of asking for a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in list(all):
    for y in list(all):
        if y[0] == x[0] and y[1] <= x[1] and y is not x:
            all.remove(y)
```

Comment: Thanks Zak! - this solution of dual looping is exactly what I needed and helps me scale up the production list which is in fact much larger and has multiple keys.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewDunlop, mark it as best answer if it solved your problem! No problem double-beep I understand, will do so on my answers in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Would something like a dictionary work better here?

```
all = [[123, 1],[456, 1],[789, 1],[123,2],[456, 2],[789,1]]

as_dict = {}
for item in all:
    if not (item[0] in as_dict and as_dict[item[0]] > item[1]):
        as_dict[item[0]] = item[1]

print(as_dict)
# Returns {123: 2, 456: 2, 789: 1}
```

In fact, if you know that the second numbers in each pair will never decrease (e.g., you won't see something like `[123,0]` appear later in the list after `[123,2]`) then just converting the list to a dictionary with `dict()` should accomplish the same thing.  Then you could convert it back to a list if you want.

```
d = dict(all)  # This is {123: 2, 456: 2, 789: 1}
newlist = [ [k,d[k]] for k in d] # This is [[123, 2], [456, 2], [789, 1]]
```